# I want to download update of apk in app without playstore

Tags: apk, auto-update

I have an app which is not on play store, so i download my app from third party custom page. Now i update that app and post it on custom page. also i gave a button on my app to download updated app. when i click on update button in app it opens a browser and download latest apk which is right, but i want to achieve that it should not open browser and download apk just like we update app on play store. I google it a lot but can not find any possible way. thanks in advance.

right now when anyone visit my page i am downloading apk by simple javascript ,

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('download-button').click();
};
```

above code download the apk on page load but i don't want to open the browser.